# javascript load image on scroll

Tags: javascript

i want to build my own **lazy images** using only javascript.

so far, this is my code :

```
<img src="images1.jpg" data-src="images2.jpg" />

var body = document.body,
    html = document.documentElement;

var height = Math.max(body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight),
    screen = screen.height; 
    img = document.getElementsByTagName("img");

    window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {

    for(var i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {

        if (img[i].clientHeight >= height - screen) {

        var data = img[i].getAttribute("data-src");
        img[i].setAttribute('src','');
        img[i].setAttribute("src", data);
        }
    }
    });
```

the problem is, the image data-src did not execute into src attribute on scroll event.

i want it to execute when the images about **200px before the viewport**.

how to doing this? and what's wrong with my code? is it possible that my **if condition** not correct?

Comment: What did you find when you stepped through the code in your debugger?

Comment: the images still images1.jpg not images2.jpg. i don't know about debugger. what's that?

Comment: Press f12 in your browser, go to the javascript debugger/console, click a line of code to add a breakpoint, then run your code. You control which line of code is executing and you can see what variables equal  what. If you are going to write code, step 1 is to learn the debugger.

Comment: There are many issues with your code, large and small. Please, learn about how to use a debugger in your main development browser first. In effect, you are using Stack Overflow, ie other people, as a debugger now. That's not what it is meant to be. Thanks.

Comment: Are you not missing `})` at the end of your Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works just fine, you need to add `});` at the end, though.

```js
var body = document.body,
    html = document.documentElement,
    height = Math.max(
               body.scrollHeight, 
               body.offsetHeight, 
               html.clientHeight, 
               html.scrollHeight, 
               html.offsetHeight),
    screen = screen.height; 
    img = document.getElementsByTagName("img");

window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {  
  for(var i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
    if (img[i].clientHeight >= height - screen) {
      var data = img[i].getAttribute("data-src");
      img[i].setAttribute('src', data);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=63&bg=FF6347&txtclr=ffffff&txt=Image-1&w=350&h=250" 
data-src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=63&bg=63FF47&txtclr=ffffff&txt=Image-1&w=350&h=250" />
<img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=63&bg=FF6347&txtclr=ffffff&txt=Image-2&w=350&h=250" 
data-src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=63&bg=63FF47&txtclr=ffffff&txt=Image-2&w=350&h=250" />
<img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=63&bg=FF6347&txtclr=ffffff&txt=Image-3&w=350&h=250" 
data-src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=63&bg=63FF47&txtclr=ffffff&txt=Image-3&w=350&h=250" />
<img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=63&bg=FF6347&txtclr=ffffff&txt=Image-4&w=350&h=250" 
data-src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=63&bg=63FF47&txtclr=ffffff&txt=Image-4&w=350&h=250" />
```

I don't get what you mean by "200px before the viewport". Could you explain it better? If you don't want all images to change at the same time, should consider the `offetTop` of each image and the `scrollTop` position. http://jsbin.com/xexeho/edit?html,js,output

Comment: thanks rafael for anwering, anyway i try ur method and why did only working on the first one images? what happend with the other?

Comment: i mean "200px before the viewport" is that images position before finally view in the website.

Comment: how to implement offsetTop and scrollTop to this function? i  thinks that's exactly what i want?

Comment: oh my god finally it's working!! thank you so much rafaelcastro! you da real MVP!!! i will always remeber u!!

Answer (score 0):

If you can mention the dimensions of the images, it would make more sense. However I am still trying to attempt to answer your question as I think the scroll event in your code wasn't triggering at all. Try making your img tag slightly below the viewport so that scroll works

Also for the calculation use window.innerHeight as it gives right height of the viewport subtracting height of the addressbar etc.

```
<img src="images1.jpg" data-src="images2.jpg" style="position:absolute;top:1169px"/>
<script>
    var body = document.body,
        html = document.documentElement;

    var height = Math.max(body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight),
        screen = window.height;
        img = document.getElementsByTagName("img");

    window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
        console.log("Checking if the scroll event is triggered...");
        for(var i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {

            if (img[i].clientHeight >= height - screen) {
                var data = img[i].getAttribute("data-src");
                img[i].setAttribute('src','');
                img[i].setAttribute("src", data);
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

OR

try using events like mousewheel and/or DOMMouseScroll which does not expect body to be actually scrollable.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [source of lazy loading plugin](https://github.com/toddmotto/echo/blob/master/src/echo.js) from todd motto.
It's pretty useful view others implementation.